# What is the best way to store multilingual data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to save/serve multilingual data in my CMS application using Mongoose.

Is this the correct way?

```
name: {
    global: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please fill name',
    },
    en_US: String,
    tr_TR: String,
    sv_SE: String
}
```

Comment: How are you defining 'correct' here?  Are you asking if that will work?  Sure.

Comment: There is never a *best* way. Only the way which works best for *you*.

Comment: A mongoose plugin can be great but I couldn't find any. Transmeta for Django do this very well.

Answer (score 3):

I do not this that you have any "correct" or "bad" way, it is mostly based on your application design and requirements.

However, you may have noticed that in MongoDB 2.6.x the Full Text Search feature supports multi languages indexing and search if you specify a language in a document. This allow you to search text by language.

Documents look like:

```
{
_id: 1,
   language: "portuguese",
   original: "A sorte protege os audazes.",
   translation:
     [
        {
           language: "english",
           quote: "Fortune favors the bold."
        },
        {
           language: "spanish",
           quote: "La suerte protege a los audaces."
        }
    ]
}
```

for more informations:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages